# How to open .bat file in VSCode using raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, linux, python-3

From the website ( https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/jsturtevant/Setting-up-Project-Oxford-for-Python-on-Windows ) at about 4:27, the author opens the activate.bat file by using `code .env\Scripts\activate.bat`, however, when I run that, they'll show bash: code: command not found. I have also tried with `vscode .env\Scripts\activate.bat` to no avail.

I remember that from: [python.exe file not found; creating "virtual environment"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77756/python-exe-file-not-found-creating-virtual-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
you suggested using source .env/bin/activate ; however, I soon realize that it only creates venv and does not open the activate.bat file on VSCode for me to edit the API code in, When I force open it using the Code-OSS, it shows an empty file. However, when I try to open it using notepad, it shows the code in it as follows:

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
        hash -r
    fi

    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/pi/happy-image-tester-django/env"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ; in bash
if [ -n "$PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x(env) " != x ] ; then
 PS1="(env) $PS1"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
    hash -r
fi
```

Therefore, may I ask if I can just key in the 3 lines of codes:

```
line 61: SET “OXFORD-KEY=________”
62
63 :END
```

into the notepad directly and save it? I believe I cant do that as the file seem to have compressed into the format suitable for raspbian somewhere when the program is installed. Hence, may I know what code I should key in instead to open the bat file properly to be able to edit it? Thank you!!!

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

3rd python script (combine.py) from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601996/combining-two-python-scripts-to-run-as-one-program:

```
def code1():
    import capture.py

def code2():
    import manage.py

code1()
code2()
```

Upon runninng:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/happy-image-tester-django $  OXFORD_KEY=1234567890 python capture.py runserver
```

Should I do the 1st method above or the 2nd method which is inserting the oxford_key into the combine.py scripts as shown below:

```
def code1():
    import capture.py

def code2():
    import manage.py

code1()
OXFORD_KEY=1234567890
code2()
```

and then runs this directly without having to input the oxford key in the command prompt any longer:
    (env) pi@raspberrypi:~/happy-image-tester-django $ python capture.py runserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is setting an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) called `OXFORD_KEY`. That's not an unusual thing to do for sensitive data (e.g. passwords and tokens) as opposed to hard-coding it into the program.

While you could edit the activate script to create the environment variable there, I personally wouldn't. They aren't really designed to be tampered with, and as you can see, it's not a trivially short script and so I'd err on the side of doing things more conventionally.

Consider some of the more standards ways of setting an environment variable:

#### 1. For one command

```
OXFORD_KEY=yourkeyhere <command>
```

If you know specifically which command needs the environment setting, you can set the environment variable *just for one time* by setting it, then typing the command you want to run.

I suspect if you did this, you'd need to run `OXFORD_KEY=key python manage.py runserver`.

#### 2. For a terminal session

This is probably the most straightforward option — run:

```
export OXFORD_KEY=key
```

in your terminal, on a new line. Then, the variable is set until you close your terminal.

#### 3. Using .bashrc

If you wanted to set the variable *permanently*, add

```
export OXFORD_KEY=key
```

to `.bashrc` in your home directory. Note that if the key is sensitive, this isn't such a good idea.

---

Ultimately, if you want a quick fix, run:

```
export OXFORD_KEY=key
```

And then skip the step of editing the `activate` script. You'll need to re-enter the key at every terminal restart — if that's a problem, see "Using .bashrc" for a more permanent solution.

---

For running the scripts in series, you probably don't want to use a Python script, but rather a Bash shell script. Create a file called `run.sh` with the following contents:

```
export OXFORD_KEY=yourkey
python capture.py 
python manage.py
```

(pass any command line options as appropriate)

Then, run the following, to make your script executable:

```
chmod +x ./run.sh
```

And to run your script:

```
./run.sh
```

Bash scripts, in their simplest form, just act as if each command was typed out on a new line in your terminal. This should be the most straightforward way for you to run multiple commands in series like this.

The `export` will set the environment variables for the length of the script, but won't last after the script ends.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the first suggestion for now as my key subscription expires periodically. Also, may I ask 1 seemingly simple qn? I have another file called capture.py, and I want it to run before manage.py (this file); hence, may I know if I can create another script to merge the 2 scripts using the method shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601996/combining-two-python-scripts-to-run-as-one-program ; by "10-yr-old"'s comment. I'm not very sure as to why that comment have -1 as not useful comment, does it not work that way? The merge codes are edited in the post above.

Comment: @GoodCodes I've edited with my suggestions; while you could do it from Python, the more obvious way is to use a shell script to run your commands. That answer is downvoted not because it's actually *wrong*... more that it's bad practice when programming, and the other solutions are cleaner.

Comment: Ohh,thankssss! I see, I see; may I ask that since you said that using .bashrc would set the variable permanently, am I still able to change the variable (OXFORD_KEY)  using the run.sh method as my oxford key would be changed every couple of weeks? And hence, does it mean that I have to edit the file "run.sh" -> chmod +x ./run.sh -> ./run.sh everytime I change the oxford key?

Comment: The chmod only needs to be done once — it just sets the file to be executable, and that's saved forever. If you put `OXFORD_KEY` in the `run.sh` script, you needn't bother with `.bashrc`; just edit `run.sh` to update `OXFORD_KEY`, and then you can run it as many times as you like until the key expires.

Comment: Ok! I'll try in a moment! Thanks so muchhhhh!!!!!!!

Comment: I was further wondering if there's any command in raspbian OS to open the projectoxford file in VScode which I've downloaded using any commands. Aka, similar to using code .  in windows command prompt as shown in in the video @Aurora0001

Comment: You built VS Code from source, so it isn't added to your `PATH` and hence isn't available as a command by default. I looked at where you saved it in  your previous question, and the launch script for you is at `/home/youruser/vscode/scripts/code.sh`. You will therefore need to run `/home/youruser/vscode/scripts/code.sh <file>` in your terminal to launch it.